How may I perform bulk operations on fully arbitrary selections of users?
My company has a Drupal 10 site that I have to interact with. I do not know Drupal very well. I do know SQL and enough PHP for basic tasks. I have administrator access to the server the site is hosted on.
Many users of the site have associated one or more license plate numbers stored as taxonomy terms linked to their user ID.  I would like to delete every user associated with a license plate number that contains a vowel.
I can write the SQL to identify these users precisely:
SELECT DISTINCT users_field_data.uid, taxonomy_term_field_data.name 
FROM users_field_data 
INNER JOIN user__field_lpn_ 
  ON users_field_data.uid = user__field_lpn_.entity_id 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_field_data 
  ON taxonomy_term_field_data.tid = user__field_lpn_.field_lpn__target_id
WHERE taxonomy_term_field_data.vid='plate_no' 
  AND taxonomy_term_field_data.name REGEXP '.*[aeiouAEIOU].*' 
ORDER BY users_field_data.uid 

Unfortunately, Drupal 10 doesn't give me any clear way to execute the query as easily as I can write it.  I don't want to execute a DELETE directly on the database because this bypasses certain inner workings of Drupal, which I understand would be bad.
I've spent the past week searching through options:

The standard Views module does not seem capable of the level of selection that this query requires, or of performing the bulk user deletion once the records are identified.

The Views Calc module does not seem to solve any of the relevant limitations of the standard View module.  It also does not seem to have a D10 version.

The Views Bulk Operations module allows bulk operations once the records are selected, but it doesn't seem to add the selection ability that this requires.

The Database API looks the most usable to me, since the PHP code involved appears to be intuitive and well within my coding abilities.  However, I've been told in this question that I'm probably not supposed to do that.  Also it will require a custom module, which sounds like an unreasonable barrier to such basic, one-time interactions with my database.


A search for "drupal 10 custom sql query" or similar gives a huge number of results, indicating this is a very in-demand feature for users of this software.  Beyond the modules listed above, however, most answers involve PHP functions or code offered without much further explanation.  I assume these are intended to go in custom modules.  After a week of searching, I haven't found any clear guidance on how I'd be expected to execute this query in Drupal 10.
How should I, a person who knows how to work with databases, perform this type of basic interaction with my database in Drupal 10?

This is easily accomplished with a vanilla Drupal install (no extra modules needed). With the equivalent SQL-speak sprinkled in:

In your View, add a relationship (aliased JOIN) to the taxonomy term referenced by your field; configure it to require the relationship (INNER JOIN). Drupal will take care of joining the field table.
Add a new filter for the term name, make sure you choose the relationship you just created when prompted (WHERE alias.name).
Under Operator, select Regular expression, and add your expression (REGEXP '...').
If the term reference field is configured to allow selection of more than just the vocabulary you're interested in, add another filter to confine results to the correct vocabulary.
To your fields, add the User: Bulk update, and tick the Cancel the selected user account(s) option (on execution, DELETE FROM ...).

Your View will now be filtered by users with a taxonomy term whose name matches your regex, you'll have checkboxes next to each row, and a form allowing you to delete the selected rows.
